# AWS ALB target group is healthy but still not accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, sonarqube, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm running SonarQube docker using the AWS ECS (EC2 instances). The container is up and running and listening on port 9000 with the below logs:-

```
q-process5925788013780644631properties
2021.03.17 15:50:55 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[web] is up
2021.03.17 15:50:55 INFO  app[][o.s.a.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='ce', ipcIndex=3, logFilenamePrefix=ce]] from [/opt/sonarqube]: /opt/java/openjdk/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonarqube/temp -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.*|[::1] -cp ./lib/common/*:/opt/sonarqube/lib/jdbc/postgresql/postgresql-42.2.17.jar org.sonar.ce.app.CeServer /opt/sonarqube/temp/sq-process3880305865950565845properties
2021.03.17 15:51:01 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process[ce] is up
2021.03.17 15:51:01 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is up
```

I'm using the VPC mode network. I'm using an application load balancer and as per the below screenshot the target groups are healthy but I still could not access my Sonar using the load balancer URL:-

[image]

Error:-

[image]

Please advise, thanks

ALB Security group screenshot:-
[image]

Comment: What error do you get when you try? 503? socket timeout?

Comment: the site cannot be reached. I have attached the screenshot.

Comment: I'm just listening using HTTP and not HTTPS, does it have anything to do with that?

Comment: check the security group you have attached to the ALB to make sure it is not blocking the traffic.

Comment: I believe you are referring to the security group of ECS service. I have added the traffic from ALB's security group to the ECS service' security group

Comment: timeout most likely means that either means your listener on the load balancer is misconfigured or your security group is misconfigured

Comment: I just noticed that the security group attached to my ALB has a source of the same security group id only with all traffic (0 - 65535 port range). What does it mean?

Comment: It means it will only accept traffic from another interface within AWS that has that security group attached.

Comment: add ingress rule to your ALB security group to allow 0.0.0.0/0 on port 80. see if that works.

Comment: Yes, it worked...thank you, everyone.....also I thank @jordanm for making me understand this concept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alb inbound rule only allows access in from the listed security group which would block your attempt to reach the load balancer url